# how to get /etc/machine-id on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, id

seems Cygwin doesn't make a [/etc/machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) by default, how should i get a /etc/machine-id on Cygwin? i guess doing

> php -r 'echo bin2hex(random_bytes(16));' > /etc/machine-id

is close enough? but if there's a package or an official way to get it, i'm all ears

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @choroba working on a script that does a lot of initialization stuff that can be skipped on *my* pc but not when running remotely, but how should i detect that its running on my own local pc? checking /etc/machine-id is an obvious solution

Comment: @choroba come to think of it, i could probably just make a "--quickinit" argument

Comment: A better way to generate the machine UUID is : `dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id`.

Comment: @harrymc sounds good but `-bash: dbus-uuidgen: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, use [uuidgen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uuidgen.1.html).

Comment: @harrymc hmm uuidgen makes a 37 character string, but if we strip uuidgen's dashes, its 32 characters, like `uuidgen | php -r 'echo str_replace("-","",stream_get_contents(STDIN));'`  seems about right, quoting the [machine-id docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html): "The machine ID is a single newline-terminated, hexadecimal, 32-character, lowercase ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no specific requirements for the machine ID in /etc/machine-id, so any method that produces 32 hexadecimal digits will work.

Though the tools that come with systemd do use the UUIDv4 format, which has a few specific bits set here and there, so `uuidgen | sed s/-//g > /etc/machine-id` would be a "closer" choice, but that's not required (and older systemd versions didn't do it either, they used to just generate fully random IDs).

Alternatively, you could get the 'MachineGuid' field from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography in the Registry and write it to the machine-id file. That seems to be what [this Rust crate does](https://docs.rs/machine-uid/latest/machine_uid/).

But don't forget that your system has a *hostname.* It's often easier for shell scripts to check the local system's hostname than look up its machine-id. PHP has `gethostname()` for that.

Comment: thanks! nitpicking, there is at least 1 requirement: don't use /dev/zero: `This ID may not be all zeros.` -- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html